# builtin_expect in Java?

Tags: java, optimization

I am porting some of my C++ code that was highly specialized to a certain subset of problems where I manually optimized some of my algorithm convergence controls. For readability and possibly my compiler I converted the profile data to the `likely()` macros. It would be wonderful if I could include this profile information somewhere other then the comments.

Out of curiosity, does Java have anything similar to the GNU `__builtin_expect` / `likely()` hints?

Comment: If you're not running your program on an ARM CPU, there's really no reason to bother. Those macros are basically useless on any modern x86 or comparable CPU, because the branch predictors built into those are a good bit better than some static hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java profiles itself based on how it is run.  You don't need to use likely() as it will measure this itself on a per run basis.

---

For expectation you can use assertions.

```
assert condition;
```

or

```
assert condition : "Message " + value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.  The JIT will do this for you if the section of code gets executed frequently enough.